# file.size always giving 20

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I am trying to get the file `size` , but don't know why it is always returning `20`.

javascript

```
function onSubmitForm() {
        var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
        var fSize = formDOMObj.resume.size;
        alert(fSize);                 //always 20 
        //....
        return true;
}
```

html

```
<form action="/action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmSend" id="frmSend" onsubmit="return onSubmitForm();"> 
  <input type="file" name="resume" id="resume"/>
  //..
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure `size` is supposed to return the size of the file?

Comment: `input` elements have a `size attribute` that indicates the _visible amount of characters_ for most types of input fields. You're probably seeing some kind of default value. Anyway, it doesn't mean what you think it means in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `size` attribute of `input` to get the size of file, which is to specify width of input in `input` tag.

use this to get the `size` of file in `bytes`.

```
 formDOMObj.resume.files[0].size;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the File API to do what you want.
http://mailru.github.io/FileAPI/ is good text about it.

Oh, and you must take care about browser support.